# how to disappear button in android

Tags: java, android

I am working on an interface where user searches for a specific item from database. I have one EditText and button in my xml file. So i want to disappear the botton and EditText temporarily , after clicking the buuton , so that user can view the required details..
How can I implement this within same activity?

Comment: u just do button invisible for some time ..

Comment: If any answer is correct means so accept the answers.Then your points are also increased and it will attract others to answer your questions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
edittxt.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
btn.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
```

or

```
edittxt.setVisibility (View.GONE);
btn.setVisibility (View.GONE);
```

`View.INVISIBLE` means, the views will still take space on screen. Whereas, `View.GONE` means they will not take space on the screen. More [info](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setVisibility%28int%29) if you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
button.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

when you want to visible than

```
button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

Disappear means invisible,

```
edittext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

you can visible the editext,

```
edittext.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```